# Spring @Async and CompletableFuture for achieving multithreading in java

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

Do really we can achieve multithreading and increase the performance as comparable to multithreading provided by tomcat server?

Code snippet with @Async and CompletableFuture

Controller --

```
@Async("asyncExecutor")
@GetMapping("/somePath")
public CompletableFuture<...> someName( @RequestParam("someParam") String someParam) {
// code snippet
....
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ResponseEntity.ok.body(response));

} catch (Exception e) {
 // code snippet
...
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ResponseEntity.status(400).body(response));
}
```

Service --

```
@Override
public String someName(String someParam) {
// code snippet including DB calls (repository class calls)
}
```

So, will the above method really improve the performance as comparable to tomcat multithreading?

I checked with some 20-50 concurrent reqs using JMeter and I am getting better response time in tomcat multithreading as comparable to the above code which is using @Async and CompletableFuture.

Or

My implementation is wrong?

Comment: Not clear why you expect the code using async to perform better.

Comment: Since it will be called asynchronously so it should perform better than the synchronous calls made by tomcat ? isn't it ?

Comment: "asynchronous" doesn't mean "faster". Asynchronicity generally means having additional complexity to synchronize and switch contexts. But if your server is waiting for other tasks to finish, then asynchronous code can help. It all depends. There is no one-size-fits-all answer.